# Select and highlight one random cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an excel spreadsheet that when a user clicks Go, it assigns a new random number to the cells in the worksheet. The range value is between 1 and 500 in a 20 by 25 matrix. I want to randomly select and change the background color to red for only one cell every time a user clicks the 'Go' button. Code below is currently assigning random numbers to the cells and selecting and highlighting a random cell. However, when Go is clicked again the previously selected cell is still highlighted along with the newly selected cell. How can I code it to only highlight the newly selected cell when clicking Go?

```
Public Sub GenerateRandom()
    Set MyRange = Range("C4:AA23")
        For i = 1 To 500
            MyRange.Cells(i) = i
        Next
        For Each Cell In MyRange
            swapcell = 1 + Int(Rnd * 500)
            savedValue = Cell.Value
            Cell.Value = MyRange.Cells(swapcell).Value
            MyRange.Cells(swapcell) = savedValue
        Next

       With MyRange.Cells(1 + Int(Rnd * 500))
                MyRange.Cells(RndBetween(1, 500)).Interior.Color = vbRed        
      End With        
    End Sub

    Public Function RndBetween(ByVal Low, ByVal High) As Integer
       Randomize
       RndBetween = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd + Low)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Color question has been answered.  But there are other issues in your code, notably that your shuffle is *biased*, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias)

Here's a version that fixes the Modulo Bias mentioned in the link, together with a number of other issues

```
Public Sub GenerateRandom()
    'declare variables
    Dim MyRange As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim swapcell As Long, savedValue As Long
    Dim idx As Long

    Randomize 'only need this once
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:AA23") 'or specify a specific sheet
    For i = 1 To MyRange.Cells.Count ' link size to specified range
        MyRange.Cells(i) = i
    Next
    For idx = MyRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        swapcell = RndBetween(1, idx) 'remove modulo bias
        savedValue = MyRange.Cells(idx).Value
        MyRange.Cells(idx).Value = MyRange.Cells(swapcell).Value
        MyRange.Cells(swapcell) = savedValue
    Next

    MyRange.Interior.Color = xlNone 'remove colour
    'removed unused With block
    MyRange.Cells(RndBetween(1, MyRange.Cells.Count)).Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub

'declare types
Public Function RndBetween(ByVal Low As Long, ByVal High As Long) As Long
    RndBetween = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd + Low)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the above link. It's been over 10 years since I've coded in VBA so I'm a little rusty.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, clearing the range colour before you highlight a cell is the quickest way. But if the background colours of your cells are set to something else then the following should work:

**Alternate Solution:**
Store the location and colour of the cell to highlight cell, then restore it's original colour on each run. You would declare the location outside the sub so that it doesn't disappear once the sub ends. This would help if your background colours are something else. Problem with this is it only works during an Excel session, if you close and save the location would have been lost, unless you saved it to a hidden sheet = unnecessary complexity for this task.

```
    Dim OriginalCell As Range
    Dim OriginalCol

    Public Sub GenerateRandom()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim NewCell As Range

    Set myRange = Range("C4:AA23")

    For i = 1 To 500
        myRange.Cells(i) = i
    Next

    For Each Cell In myRange
        swapcell = 1 + Int(Rnd * 500)
        savedValue = Cell.Value
        Cell.Value = myRange.Cells(swapcell).Value
        myRange.Cells(swapcell) = savedValue
    Next

    ''''new code
    Set NewCell = myRange.Cells(RndBetween(1, MyRange.Cells.Count))

    If OriginalCell Is Nothing Then
        Set OriginalCell = NewCell
        OriginalCol = OriginalCell.Interior.Color
    Else
        OriginalCell.Interior.Color = OriginalCol
        Set OriginalCell = NewCell
        OriginalCol = OriginalCell.Interior.Color
    End If

    NewCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    '''''

    End Sub
```

On a side note, sending ranges to array and working with the array is much faster, but that's another topic. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Clear the color of the range before setting the color of the random cell:

```
Public Sub GenerateRandom()
    Set Myrange = Range("C4:AA23")
        For i = 1 To 500
            Myrange.Cells(i) = i
        Next
        For Each Cell In Myrange
            swapcell = 1 + Int(Rnd * 500)
            savedValue = Cell.Value
            Cell.Value = Myrange.Cells(swapcell).Value
            Myrange.Cells(swapcell) = savedValue
        Next

       Myrange.Interior.Color = xlNone
       With Myrange.Cells(1 + Int(Rnd * 500))
                Myrange.Cells(RndBetween(1, 500)).Interior.Color = vbRed
      End With
    End Sub

    Public Function RndBetween(ByVal Low, ByVal High) As Integer
       Randomize
       RndBetween = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd + Low)
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have known it was going to be something simple. SMH.